# Cómo ejecutar && en powershell

Tags: cmd, powershell, go

Estoy intentando correr un servidor Web construído con Go, encontré que puede hacerse con:

```
go build -o ejecutable.exe && ejecutable.exe
```

pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
PS C:\Users\go-project> go build -o ejecutable.exe && ejecutable.exe
At line:1 char:28
+ go build -o ejecutable.exe && ejecutable.exe
+                            ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

La misma instrucción desde CMD corre sin problemas, entiendo que es PowerShell (dentro de Visual Studio Code) quien no entiende el &&

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Antes de nada, creo que es interesante aprender qué es exactamente el operador `&&` que mencionas. En StackOverflow en inglés, **Iszi** hace la misma pregunta que tú y menciona lo siguiente:<sup>[1]</sup>

> En el procesador CMD nativo de Windows se puede usar `&` para concatenar programas con el objetivo de que se ejecute uno inmediatamente después de otro. Al poner `&&` se ejecutará el segundo comando solo si el primero se completa sin ningún error.

Es decir, que básicamente lo que hace el comando que nos has compartido es ejecutar dos comandos uno detrás de otro: primero `go build -o ejecutable.exe`, para compilar el ejecutable, y luego, si el comando anterior se completa sin ningún error (es decir, se compila correctamente el código), ejecuta `ejecutable.exe`.

Así pues, una solución simple sería ejecutar los dos comandos separados manualmente.

Aun así, en esa misma pregunta, hay una respuesta de **SS4Soku** que nos explica cuales son los equivalentes a estos operadores en PowerShell:<sup>[2]</sup>

> El operador `&` en PowerShell es simplemente un punto y coma: `;`
>
> El operador `&&` en PowerShell tiene que ejecutarse como si fuera una sentencia `if`:
>
> `Comando ; if($?) {Comando}`

En conclusión, lo equivalente sería ejecutar: `go build -o ejecutable.exe ; if($?) { .\ejecutable.exe }`.

[1]: https://superuser.com/q/464109/124677
[2]: https://superuser.com/a/464117/124677

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que hice fue crear un archivo.ps1 para no tener que escribir todo el comando como lo menciona **Adrià Vilanova**.

Después, buscando encontré un [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37724701/9996904) que sirve para observar archivos y realizar una acción cuando hay cambios en los archivos. Este script lo modifique un poco y lo pegue en la raíz de mi proyecto

```
## Original code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37724701/9996904
$global:app = $null
Function RunMyStuff {
    Clear-Host
    # this is the bit we want to happen when the file changes
    Write-Host "**********************************************************************************"
    Write-Host "**********************************************************************************"
    Write-Host "**********************************************************************************"
    Write-Host "**********************************************************************************"
    go install github.com/username/myapp ;
    if ($?) {
        if ( $global:app -ne $null){
            Stop-Process -id $global:app.id
        }
        $global:app = Start-Process -NoNewWindow "myapp" -passthru
    }
}

Function Watch {
    $global:FileChanged = $false # dirty... any better suggestions?
    $folder = "."
    $filter = "*.go"
    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
        IncludeSubdirectories = $true
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }

    Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Changed" -Action {$global:FileChanged = $true} > $null

    while ($true){
        while ($global:FileChanged -eq $false){
            # We need this to block the IO thread until there is something to run
            # so the script doesn't finish. If we call the action directly from
            # the event it won't be able to write to the console
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
        }

        # a file has changed, run our stuff on the I/O thread so we can see the output
        RunMyStuff

        # reset and go again
        $global:FileChanged = $false
    }
}

RunMyStuff # run the action at the start so I can see the current output
Watch
```

Comment: por favor considera editar y añadir el contenido de los enlaces aquí, pues si esos links se rompen con el tiempo, entonces la respuesta pierde valor